# Emacsのbackward-kill-word に当たる編集操作を RubyMine行う方法

Tags: rubymine

Emacsで`(global-set-key "\C-w" 'backward-kill-word)`とカーソルから左方向に一単語をkillする操作をRubyMineでも行いたいのですが該当する機能を見つけられませんでした。

そのような操作をRubyMineで行う方法はありますか？

### 追記

RubyMineに対する要望としてReportしておきました。まだ誰にもAssignされていませんので、もし同じ機能を希望してる方がいましたら up vote よろしくお願いします。
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-16882

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ALT(Option)+Backspace ではどうでしょうか？
以下の参考サイトで'Word'で検索するといろいろ見つかります。

参考サイト
https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/help/basic-editing.html

Comment: ありがとうございます。`Delete to Word Start in Different "CamelHumps" Mode`が近い動作でした。欲を言えばdelete ではなく直後に `Ctrl+y`でyankできるkillが欲しかったのですが、なさそうですのそれは要望に出してみます。